# GoJS showing incorrect diagram type

Tags: javascript, json, gojs

I need to generate a diagram that is able to display data from JSON which came from the server.
I use GoJS to generate a diagram. So I used a sample from the site to build my own project. Everything looks perfect like I wanted.

```
myDiagram.model = new go.TreeModel([
    { key: "Root", wallet: "data", color: lavgrad },
    { key: "Left1", wallet: "data", parent: "Root", dir: "left", color: bluegrad },
    { key: "Left3", wallet: "data", parent: "Root", dir: "left", color: bluegrad },
    { key: "leaf1", wallet: "data", parent: "Left1" },
    { key: "leaf2", wallet: "data", parent: "Left1" },
    { key: "Left2", wallet: "data", parent: "Left1", color: bluegrad },
    { key: "leaf3", wallet: "data", parent: "Left2" },
    { key: "leaf4", wallet: "data", parent: "Left2" },
    { key: "Right1", wallet: "data", parent: "Root", dir: "right", color: yellowgrad },
    { key: "Right2", wallet: "data", parent: "Right1", color: yellowgrad },
    { key: "leaf5", wallet: "data", parent: "Right2" },
    { key: "leaf6", wallet: "data", parent: "Right2" },
    { key: "leaf7", wallet: "data", parent: "Right2" },
    { key: "leaf8", wallet: "data", parent: "Right1" },
    { key: "leaf9", wallet: "data", parent: "Right1" }
]);
doubleTreeLayout(myDiagram);
```

[first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEKJD.png)

After this, I tried to remove the hardcoded diagram structure and parse it from JSON instead. Here is my code.

JSON file

```
{
  "data":[
    {
      "key": "Root",
      "wallet": "data"
    },
    {
      "key": "Left1",
      "wallet": "data",
      "parent": "Root",
      "dir": "left"
    },
    {
      "key": "Left3",
      "wallet": "data",
      "parent": "Root",
      "dir": "left"
    },
    {
      "key": "leaf1",
      "wallet": "data",
      "parent": "Left1"
    },
    {
      "key": "leaf2",
      "wallet": "data",
      "parent": "Left1"
    },
    {
      "key": "Left2",
      "wallet": "data",
      "parent": "Left1"
    },
    {
      "key": "leaf3",
      "wallet": "data",
      "parent": "Left2"
    },
    {
      "key": "leaf4",
      "wallet": "data",
      "parent": "Left2"
    },
    {
      "key": "Right1",
      "wallet": "data",
      "parent": "Root",
      "dir": "right"
    },
    {
      "key": "Right2",
      "wallet": "data",
      "parent": "Right1"
    },
    {
      "key": "leaf5",
      "wallet": "data",
      "parent": "Right2"
    },
    {
      "key": "leaf6",
      "wallet": "data",
      "parent": "Right2"
    },
    {
      "key": "leaf7",
      "wallet": "data",
      "parent": "Right2"
    },
    {
      "key": "leaf8",
      "wallet": "data",
      "parent": "Right1"
    },
    {
      "key": "leaf9",
      "wallet": "data",
      "parent": "Right1"
    }
  ]
}
```

JS file

```
jQuery.getJSON("minimal.json", load);
function load(jsondata) {
   myDiagram.model = new go.TreeModel(jsondata["data"]);
}
```

[second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWv13.png)

But As you can see the result doesn't look like in the first picture above(it's just placed in random order). That result goes without any error or warning messages in the console. So I cant figure out what I am doing wrong and why data displays in random order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's missing is the layout of the diagram.  I suggest that you use the newer Double Tree sample: https://gojs.net/latest/samples/doubleTree.html

Note how it uses the **DoubleTreeLayout** extension and sets **Diagram.layout** so that the layout happens automatically.
https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/DoubleTreeLayout.html

This is different than the older code you started from, which has a `doubleTreeLayout` function that programmatically performed the layout.

```
$(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
  {
    layout: $(DoubleTreeLayout,
      {
        // choose whether this subtree is growing towards the right or towards the left:
        directionFunction: function(n) { return n.data && n.data.dir !== "left"; }
      })
  });
```

Alternatively, you can call `doubleTreeLayout()` after you have loaded the model.  However, you would also need to do that each time the user expanded or collapsed a subtree.  Whereas by setting **Diagram.layout** the layout would automatically be performed again as nodes and links appear or disappear.